# How to call to an Umbraco dictionary item in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary, umbraco

I'm working on an Umbraco site which mostly uses .cshtml files, but for a couple small places, they use .xslt files to handle embedding videos. I don't know a thing about .xslt. But, through my googling, I've figured out what I need to put to call to a dictionary item (which will replace hard-coded text).

```
<p>umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem("NameOfDictionaryItem")</p>
```

My question is, do I need to wrap this code in something like this:

```
<xsl:blahblah>
  <p>umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem("NameOfDictionaryItem")</p>
</xsl>
```

I can show the code of the whole file if need be... Just don't know how much of it is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to select the value from the dictionary item, you need to use the xsl:value-of function:

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('NoNewsArticles')" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct way to do this:

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetDictionaryItem('NameOfDictionaryItem')" /></p>
```